# Android EditText: Wanna the cursor always shows even before user make some valid inputs

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I am doing my first android app and I hv a edittext area in which I need the cursor always show. Here "always show" means that even when a user tap the edittext for the first time, the cursor should show rather than it only gets showed after user really inputs something.

To make it clear, pls refers to the first picture and you can see when I tap the edittext area for the first time, only the softInputMethod shows but the edittext do not have a cursor:

[image: No cursor]

And pls refers to the second picture and you can find that as long as I hv make ANY valid input, the cursor shows:

[image: Have cursor]

So is anyone who can tell me how to make the cursor ALWAYS SHOW even before I really make some valid inputs (to make the cursor show in the first picture)?

For your reference, I hv already tried to use android:cursorVisible="true" , android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and even some other ways to achieve this. But none of it really fix this problem. So I really need some other suggestions.

Thanks a lot

P.S the below is my XML code for this edittext:

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/typing_text"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="@string/typing_text_hint"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:lines="6"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
    android:digits="@string/digits"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="false"

    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Can you update your manifest where you have declared this activity. The above xml code seems to have no problem for me.

Comment: I can see the cursor all the time. :-s

Answer (score 0):

```
As mentioned above, here's the actual line
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

 <EditText
               android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:id="@+id/edSMobile"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"                    
                android:inputType="phone" />
```